# Pass form plain text to URL to be populated on another page Business Catalyst

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, business-catalyst

I am cracking my head trying to pass some **PLAIN TEXT** from my check out page to a receipt page, but I have loads of limitations with the server capabilities so I believe I could possibly achieve this using Javascript but with my knowledge base I am not capable yet.

On my FORM I have it as follow:

```
<form id="ValidateOrderRegistration" name="catwebformform14103" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=10850&?buyeremail=<script>document.write(encodeURIComponent('{module_emailaddress}'))</script>&OID={module_oid}&OTYPE={module_otype}&EID={module_eid}&CID={module_cid}&CC ={module_urlcountrycode}&Referrer={module_siteurl,true,true}">
.....

<div class="cart-prod-name" id="prodName">Name as plain text</div>
<div class="cart-prod-price">Price as plain text</div>
<div class="cart-prod-qunt" id="prodQuantity">Quantity as plain text</div>

......
</form>
```

I can well transfer modules adding **?buyeremail=document.write(encodeURIComponent('{module_emailaddress}'))&** to the form action and generate on the page i need using **{module_url,buyeremail}**.

My question is How can I transfer the product **name, price and quantity** as plain text to the URL on the submit of the form so I can populate on the next page.

Some knowledge shared is much appreciated.

Comment: Better if you add hidden fields for holding the value so that at server you can access the same . So no need to trnasmit through URL

Comment: do you mean using Ajax to fetch it from another page?

Comment: From checkout post form values to receipt page where you will get hidden form field values as well

Comment: can you show me an example plz?